# Return dictionary keys and values in alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to do this exercise in a Python guide:

> Write a program that reads in a string on the command line and returns
>   a table of the letters of the alphabet in alphabetical order which
>   occur in the string together with the number of times each letter
>   occurs. Case should be ignored. A sample run of the program would look
>   like this:

```
$ python letter_counts.py "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters."
a  2
c  1
d  1
e  5
g  1
h  2
i  4
l  2
n  2
o  1
p  2
r  4
s  5
t  5
u  1
w  2
$
```

I've already written a function to count the letters and store them in a dictionary along with their corresponding values:

```
def count_all(text):
    text = text.lower()
    counts = {}
    for char in text:
        if char not in counts:
            counts.setdefault(char,1)
        else:
            counts[char] = counts[char] + 1
    print(counts)
```

but I'm ashamed to say I'm completely dumbfounded as to how you can even order items in a mapping type using any sort of rules. Would I have to convert them to a list? Would I need to use `ord()` at any point?

**EDIT:** Based on the answers I got, I managed to make the function print out the items alphabetically without having to use any methods that I don't fully understand yet. Here's the full thing:

```
def count_all(text):
    text = text.lower()
    counts = {}
    for char in text:
        if char not in counts:
            counts.setdefault(char,1)
        else:
            counts[char] = counts[char] + 1
    counts = sorted(counts.items())
    for i in counts:
        print(i[0],' ',i[1])

count_all('banana')
```

Is this a good solution? How can it be improved?

Comment: try `sorted(counts.items())`. Related: `collections.Counter` do what you want already

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` statement in the function `count_all` to return the dictionary

```
def count_all(text):
    ...
    return counts
```

Then you can use the `sorted` built-in function and a `for` loop:

```
for e in sorted(count_all("ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters").items()):
    print e[0], e[1]
```

Note that `some_dict.items()` method returns pairs of `tuple`s of the form `(key, value)`.

Also, since it look like you don't want to count "." or spaces, you could use:

```
text = "".join(text.strip(".").split()).lower()
```

Comment: Note that sorted creates a list of the key value pairs. If you want to avoid creating a list of the key values, you can do that by iterating over `string.lowercase`.

Comment: `text.replace(' ', '').replace('.', '').lower()` makes more sense than `''.join(text.strip('.').split()).lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your data in a dictionary:

```
txt='''\
a  2
c  1
d  1
e  5
g  1
h  2
i  4
l  2
n  2
o  1
p  2
r  4
s  5
t  5
u  1
w  2'''

d=dict([tuple(e.split()) for e in txt.splitlines()])
# d={'p': '2', 'r': '4', 's': '5', 't': '5', 'u': '1', 'w': '2', 'a': '2', 'c': '1', 'd': '1', 'e': '5', 'g': '1', 'h': '2', 'i': '4', 'l': '2', 'n': '2', 'o': '1'}
```

If you want to print `d` only by the key, you can just use `sorted` directly:

```
print(sorted(d.items()))
```

Now if you want to sort a) first by frequency of the letter then b) by letter:

```
li=sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1], -ord(t[0])), reverse=True)
# li=
('e', '5')
('s', '5')
('t', '5')
('i', '4')
('r', '4')
('a', '2')
('h', '2')
('l', '2')
('n', '2')
('p', '2')
('w', '2')
('c', '1')
('d', '1')
('g', '1')
('o', '1')
('u', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters.'

# Or see Python's Counter class: counts = Counter(s.lower())
counts = {}
for c in s.lower():
    counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1

for c, n in sorted(counts.items()):
    print(c, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted works, and is quite popular on stackoverflow, but is quite a bit slower than sort (both 2.x and 3.x) and tends to yield excessively-long lines of code.

So:

```
items = list(counts.items())
items.sort()
for key, value in items:
    # do something with key and value
```

The above should work on both 2.x and 3.x, though it is untested.

As was already mentioned, collections.Counter() is closer to what you want to do in this case, and is available in both 2.x and 3.x.

If you were sorting inside a loop, then you would want to use a dictionary-like tree instead of a dictionary (hash table).  But you're not, so using a dictionary and a single sort is more effective.

If you were sorting in a loop, here are several dictionary-like trees in Python (2.x and 3.x supported, including jython and pypy) that save their data in key-order:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/datastructures/
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/2014-01/

There's also what's known as collections.OrderedDict(), but it stores data in insertion-order, not key order.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I got the same homework and managed to solve it.
PS: This is my own idea so there might be a better way.

```
diction ={}
Input = input()
INPUT = Input.lower()
characterlist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
for i in characterlist:
    diction[i]= INPUT.count(i,0,100)
    if diction[i]==0:
        del diction[i]

for k in diction:
    print(k,diction[k])
```